# VSCode. Change tab size for markdown code preview

Tags: visual-studio-code

It is possible to change tab size for markdown code preview ? Currently 1 tab = 8 spaces.

Comment: Are you referring to the editor window or the markdown preview window? For the markdown preview you can apply your own css using the markdown.styles setting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are referring to the markdown preview window you can apply custom css to manipulate the way it is displayed using the markdown.styles setting.

```
"markdown.styles": [
        "Style.css"
    ]
```

If you are referring to the editor window you can set the tab size for markdown files by editing your settings file:

```
"[markdown]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 4
  }
```

To access the settings file click File -> Preferences -> Settings

Comment: The path to the css is relative to the current workspace, so create a `Style.css` file in your workspace root for hte sample.  This css works for tab size:

`pre { tab-size: 4; }`

Comment: @JasonGoemaat
According to this [PR on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/77745/commits/c5ab082ed7de081cdcbb32b8d2be3f2601e3d1e9), the correct code to change tab size is : `pre code { tab-size: 8; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that file "https://github.com/SepCode/vscode-markdown-style/blob/master/preview/github.css", we know that "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SepCode/vscode-markdown-style/master/preview/github.css", the URL is not working.

I have a good idea, we can use Github Pages.

Add a submodule in your repository, like this "`git submodule add https://github.com/SepCode/vscode-markdown-style.git`". And now we can use the URL "https://sepcode.github.io/vscode-markdown-style/preview/github.css" set markdown.styles.

Step:

- clone your GitHub pages "`git clone https://github.com/SepCode/SepCode.github.io.git`"
- `cd SepCode.github.io`
- `git submodule add https://github.com/SepCode/vscode-markdown-style.git`
- `git commit -am 'added vscode-markdown-style module'`
- `git push`
- setting vscode setting.json

  ```
  {
      "markdown.styles":["https://sepcode.github.io/vscode-markdown-style/preview/github.css"]
  }
  ```

the vscode-markdown-style repository is just an example, we should use ourself's CSS file. This way is more convenient and controllable.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try! \

```
$~~~~~~~~~~~$ = 10 spaces
```